# Start/Stop receiving data on UDP port on a timed interval

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, dispose

I have a function that listens for UDP packets on a specific port. Whenever I receive data, I want the function to STOP receiving data on that port, wait 5 seconds, then resume listening for data. The basic flow is:

1. Listen for UDP packets.
2. Receive a UDP packet and do any necessary processing of that data.
3. Block incoming UDP packets and wait 5 seconds.
4. Repeat.

I have the function working, but I can't figure out how to block UDP packets during the 5-second wait period. I've used the `EnableBroadcast` boolean on the `UdpClient`, but it does nothing. I've also tried setting the `SocketOptionName` of `Broadcast` and `BlockSource` to true/false and it does nothing as well.

```
private async void ReceiveUdpPackets()
{
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            while (receivePackets)
            {
                Log.Info("Listening for UDP packets...");

                listener.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Udp, SocketOptionName.BlockSource, false);
                byte[] bytes = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);
                listener.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Udp, SocketOptionName.BlockSource, true);

                Log.Info($"Received UDP broadcast from {groupEP} :");
                Log.Info($"{Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)}");

                var bString = BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", "");
                Log.Info("UDP ByteString: " + bString);

                DecodeByteString(bString);
                await Task.Delay(5000);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("There was an issue decoding the UDP packet: " + ex.ToString());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `SocketOptionName.BlockSource` is not a valid option for `SocketOptionLevel.Udp`.  It is used for `SocketOptionLevel.IP` instead to manage multicast memberships.  The only way to make a UDP socket stop listening for packets is to close the socket. Otherwise, I would suggest moving the socket to another thread, or use an asynchronous read, that monitors for and discards any new data during those 5 seconds, and then you can retrieve the socket, or cancel the read, when you are ready.

Comment: Do you care what happens to the incoming UDP datagrams?  Could you simply read them without doing anything with them... for 5 seconds?  Or do you want the remote peer to fail when it tries to send them?

Comment: Personally, id just go with signalr, it will be easier to setup, easier to maintain, and easier to get right

Answer (score 0):

If you want clients to be unable to send anything during the waiting period, you'll need some sort of way for them to know that the server isn't in a listening state. You could run a separate task on a different port, which clients may query to see if data can be transmitted and processed on the main port. There are many ways to go about this, but the basic idea is as simple as it sounds: the client queries the secondary port, the server responds with a message indicating whether or not the primary port is "online". If not, the client waits until it receives the go-ahead from the server. If so, the client can immediately send its information over.

If that doesn't sound appealing, you can also implement a data queuing model on the server side. You could have one task populate a [BlockingCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=netframework-4.8) with incoming data from client(s) and another thread to process data drawn from this source. Note that this wouldn't stop transmissions, so it's not a perfect solution to your problem, but it does have several benefits. Here's a (flawed) example of what the code might look like:

```cs
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ExampleNamespace
{

    /* 
     * data class; encapsulates byte array data received from a client. 
     * in an actual implementation this might be a nice spot to put code 
     * that interprets bytes from the client in some way
     */
    public class Transmission
    {
        public IPEndPoint Client { get; set; }

        public byte[] Data { get; set; }

        public Transmission(IPEndPoint client, byte[] data)
        {
            Client = client;
            Data = data;
        }
    }

    public class Server
    {
        private UdpClient listener;

        /*
         * you probably want to make this a bounded collection to prevent the
         * collection from getting too big
         */
        private BlockingCollection<Transmission> dataReceived = new BlockingCollection<Transmission>();

        private bool receivePackets = true;

        private bool processData = true;

        private IPEndPoint groupEP;

        public Server(IPEndPoint listenAt)
        {
            listener = new UdpClient(listenAt);
            groupEP = listenAt;
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            ProcessData();
            ReceiveData();
        }

        public async void ReceiveData()
        {
            await Task.Run(() => {
                while (receivePackets)
                {
                    byte[] data = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);
                    dataReceived.Add(new Transmission(groupEP, data));
                }
            });
        }

        public async void ProcessData()
        {
            //you could run just a few of these to increase your processing 
            //speed without changing how things work
            await Task.Run(async () => {
                while (processData)
                {
                    //blocks until data is available
                    Transmission data = dataReceived.Take();

                    //do things with the data...

                    await Task.Delay(5000);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

As stated, this example has some issues — if you want to actually implement this I highly recommend looking into making `dataReceived` a bounded blocking collection so you don't have to worry about memory issues. Also, it's generally useful to be able to shut down the whole process by passing a [CancellationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=netframework-4.8) to your Take() and TryTake() calls, as well as any threads you create. However, the design itself should allow for easy multitasking in the event that processing clients becomes a performance problem.